# Save Matlab audio output

Tags: matlab, audio

I need to save the audio output of a script in Matlab but I don't know how to do it. It is a complex sound, with several pauses of silence with different durations, so I cannot simply use audiowrite. Is it possible to record the output? I would like to save exactly what I hear after running the script. It is my first time with sounds in Matlab and I did not find anything online. Thank you for your help.

Comment: when you say audio output what do you mean, recording the sound in your speakers? or saving some spectrogram? why do you have to use matlab and not any recorder? how do you produce the sound? a minimal working example would help us help you

Comment: The sound is produced in matlab and I need to record the sound in the speakers. A simple example: for ii = 1:length(cf) - 1 sound(s(ii,:), sf); % sound presentation pause(d + 0.025); % waiting for sound end+silent period end where d is the sound duration and 0.025 is the duration of the silence. For my understanding, I need one single matrix S to save a file using audiowrite(S,Fs). I was thinking in creating a vector describing the silent period, but as it has a different duration with respect to the sound so the # of columns would be different. @bla

Comment: the example you gave in your comment is not satisfactory. please edit your **question** and add a minimal and working example. by "working" I mean that I can copy and paste it verbatim an it'll work on my computer. If you need help with that, ask.

Comment: another thing, you have the audio and you play it using matlab , correct? so you have it! if it is made of several `sf(ii,:)` you can concatenate them to a single one, for example, `sall=sf(:);`

Answer (score 0):

Represent pauses like sounds with zeros:

```
signal1 = ...;
pause1 = zeros(length1/fs,1);
signal2 = ...;
pause2 = zeros(length1/fs,1);
```

and just concatenate all signals in one array:

```
longSignal = [signal1; pause1; signal2; pause2];
```

and use `audiowrite` to save your long signal in a wav file.